# Run DXL from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ibm-doors

Is there is any way to execute doors dxl from Excel VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can run a DOORS dxl script via command line- and you can run in batch mode if you don't want to open the DOORS interface to the user.

Be aware some behaviors of DOORS are different in batch mode.